# Why are my If-statements not working out properly?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, logic

Im trying to write a Python program where everytime I enter an input, it will return a score of 0,1,2, or 3.
if my classification is less than 2, it return a score of 0
if my classification is greater than -2 and less than 2. It returns a score of 1 and so on.
However, it says that the code on my elif statement is invalid syntax.
How can I approach this problem?

Logic Flow

```
# Part 1

def fahrToCelsius():

    fahr = float(input("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit one more time: "))

    cel = round((fahr - 32) / 1.8, 2)

    return cel

​

# Part 2

def tempClassifier(cel):

    if cel < -2:

        return 0

    elif cel >= -2 and cel <= 2:

        return 1

    elif cel > 2 and cel <= 15:

        return 2

    elif cel > 15:

        return 3

    else:

        print("The value is not a valid temperature")

​



fahr = float(input("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: "))

cel = fahrToCelsius()

classification = tempClassifier(cel)

​# **I NEED HELP RIGHT HERE -- see the code below**

if classification <-2:

    placeholder = "1"

elif classification >= -2 and <= 2:

    placeholder = "2"

elif classification > 2 and <= 15:

    placeholder = "3"

elif classification > 15:

    placeholder = "4"

else:

    return = "not a valid temperature"

​

print(f"A temperature of {fahr} Fahrenheit or {cel} Celsius is considered a number {placeholder} ")
```

This gives the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\playm\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9712\2457290799.py", line 27
    elif classification >= -2 and <= 2:
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You seem to have a problem with your indentation.  Paste your code examples again, highlight each code block, and press the `{}` button in the editor bar.

Comment: You seem to already know how to write an `if` statement with multiple conditions, as evidenced by the code in the `tempClassifier` function. How did you forget that when writing the subsequent block of code that gives you the syntax error?

Comment: Same for the `return` statement later in your code. If you copied the code in the functions from somewhere, try to study the syntax and understand why that code behaves the way it does, so that you can use those same concepts in your own code.

Comment: Also, `return` needs to be in a _function_. Your (currently invalid) return statement isn't in a function, so you can expect another error there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, indentation is fine. The problems is this is how your line 27 should look:

```
elif classification >= -2 and classification <= 2 :
```

You need the variable compared with each condition.

Comment: A more pythonic way to write this `if -2 <= classification <= 2`

Answer (score 0):

The error here is caused by how python treats these boolean operations.

To use the "and" statement in python you must have two valid truth statements either side of the and.

For example:
`x > 1 and x < 3`
If you were to take either of these two truth statements and put them in a single if they would still work.

What you have above is
`classification >= -2 and <= 2`

If we take each of the statements we have:

Statement 1: `classification >= -2`

Statement 2: `<=2`

The interpreter isn't clever enough to realize statement 2 is  still comparing against classification. To make this work all you need to do is amend the statement like so:
`classification >= -2 and classification <=2`

The error your console is spitting out is pointing to the location where it believes there is a missing variable/value. The `<=2` with nothing on it's left hand side making it an invalid statement.